# how can i create a dynamic page in asp.net (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added a page "First.aspx" in my website application. Inside First.aspx page i have a  button named btnbutton.
    "onclick" Event of "btnbutton" a new dynamic page should open.
    how can i do this.?
    Please Remember the new dynamic page created, is not in existing in the application. This       page should be created at runtime and dynamic also.
    please help me out!

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing as the "Dynamicly created ASP.NET pages" you are asking about ...

Comment: Akram Shahda: i dont think so

Comment: It would be much better if you will explain in plain English ( without programming jargon ) what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @eugeneK: I would like to open new page in runtime and that on that page i want one textbox and one button

Comment: @amitvyas100688: To open an ASP.NET page, the code behind must be compiled. How would you compile the code of the generated page ??

Comment: @Akram Shahda: That i dont knw so that i ask this question brother

Comment: @amitvyas100688, you still using programming jargon because i'm 90% sure you not trying to do what you are saying you want.

Comment: @amitvyas100688: That's logicaly impossible. I dont know if there is any unlogical solution for it ...

Comment: @Akram Shahda: ok thnx brother i try to do that thing if i get solution i give u ok

Comment: First.aspx is a dynamic page already, just have it reload showing your textbox and button instead when you click the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about generating *ASP.NET* pages at *runtime*, that is impossible. The reason is the following:

> You need to compile the code of the
>   `ASP.NET` page before run it. And that
>   is impossible after your web
>   application has started.

However, if you are asking about navigation between pages, then, you could use `Response.Redirect`:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Comment: that i know about Navigation bro but i want to create a new page after my web application started. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can create new Dynamic File in ASP.net website (Not in a ASP.net Web Application).
But there is a problem . Once you created a file the whole Website will be restarted for compiling the newly created file. So you Session data will be lost.

Here is the code to create new file.

```
    string fielName = Server.MapPath("~/file.aspx");
        //File.Create(fielName);
        //File.AppendText(fielName);


        // create a writer and open the file
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fielName);

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(@"<%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true""  CodeFile=""file.aspx.cs"" Inherits=""file"" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">

<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head runat=""server"">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id=""form1"" runat=""server"">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
");

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();


        tw = new StreamWriter(fielName + ".cs");

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(@"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class file : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Write(""new File "");

    }
}
");

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();
```

Comment: suppose i have to give dynamic name of my page written in my text box and also change the name of CodeFile="" Inherits="" which is in html page what shall i do?? i have tried CodeFile="""+Textbox1.Text+""" Inherits="""+Textbox1.Text+""" but showing error

Comment: wht error you are getting..? you have to change the name here also .. `Server.MapPath("~/file.aspx")`

Comment: The error i am getting is:-    Compiler Error Message: CS1010:  Newline in constant

       // write a line of text to the file
       tw.WriteLine(@"<%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true""  CodeFile="""+TextBox1.Text+".cs"" Inherits="""+TextBox1.Text+""" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">

Comment: this is just a problem with formatting the literal string. Try this code `tw.WriteLine(@"<%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true"" CodeFile=""" + TextBox1.Text + @".cs"" Inherits=""" + TextBox1.Text + @""" `