# Asp.net Dynamic page Creation issues

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, seo

I created a aspx blog website which creates page dynamically. 
and uses unique id generated at the time of page creation as it's name.

eg:
http://www.websitename.com/2016/f1.aspx

`http://www.websitename.com/2016/f2.aspx`

`http://www.websitename.com/2016/f3.aspx`

If i use this naming convention, do i have to worry about SEO problems? 
whether the the search engines index my website and the blogs?

I need to change the dynamically created page name to the page title. How can i do it?

and also i need to remove the .aspx from the blog page.

eg :

/f1.aspx => /HelloWorld

/f2.aspx => /ThisCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... although i didn't tried it myself yet... but i am pretty sure ..it should work... Add these lines in your webconfig to remove .aspx extension from the end...

```
 <configuration>
  <system.webserver>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
        <rule name="RemoveASPX" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AddASPX" enabled="true">
            <match url=".*" negate="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
        </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webserver>
```

Comment: Thanks @mridul-koul, extension .aspx issues is solved. thanks for that. is there any way to rename the dynamically generated page name to the title of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links.... these might come handy

[how to change title of aspx page dynamically on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982811/how-to-change-title-of-aspx-page-dynamically-on-page-load)

[Page.Title vs Title tag in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224443/page-title-vs-title-tag-in-asp-net)

[how can i create a dynamic page in asp.net (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198463/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-page-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: i'm sorry, what i meant was, changing the URL name of that page. (Ex: http://www.websitename.com/2016/f2.aspx to http://www.websitename.com/2016/helloworld) helloworld is the blog title of the page f2.aspx